# What's the Efficacy of Ampakines in the Treatment for ADHD?

Tags: pharmacology

What's the Efficacy of Ampakines in the Treatment for ADHD? Ampakines are a class of drugs that serve as potentiators of the AMPA glutamate receptor. By so doing they serve as nootropic, anxiolytics and antidepressants.

Comment: Health stackexchange?